# Getting 401 on PATCH Request sent with AFNetworking/RestKit but 202 sent from Browser

Tags: ios, django, restkit, afnetworking, tastypie

So I have this RESTful API running on top of my Django server by using Tastypie.
So I am doing the following code from javascript, and everything works fine.

```
       var newData = {};
       newData["content"] = "This is a new test";
       $.ajax({ 
           type: 'patch',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           url: "/api/rest/sopsteps/17/",
           data: JSON.stringify(newData),
           dataType: "json",                    
           success: function(data, status) {
               alert("success");
           },
           error: function(data, status){
               alert(data + " STATUS : " + status);
           },
       });
```

Now if I do the following using AFNetworking/RestKit I always get a 401 back.

[26/Dec/2012 16:20:20] "PATCH /api/rest/sopsteps/17/ HTTP/1.1" 401 0

```
NSDictionary* params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: _contentTextView.text, @"content", nil];



NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api/rest/sopsteps/%@/",((PokaSOPStep *)_step).identifier];


[[objectManager HTTPClient]patchPath:path parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     _step.content = _contentTextView.text;
     NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString);
 }
                            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     if(operation.responseData)
     {
         id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseData options:0 error:nil];
         if(!json)
         {
             NSLog(@"An unexpected error occurred. No JSON from Server");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"An unexpected error occurred.");
         }
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"The Server is currently not responding.");
     }

 }];
```

but if I do it from the browser, I get:

[26/Dec/2012 16:54:57] "PATCH /api/rest/sopsteps/17/ HTTP/1.1" 202 0

Any ideas?! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any type of authorization you are using on the django end here?

Answer (score 0):

401 is the HTTP code for "unauthorized". The reason you're getting different results in the browser and AFNetworking is that you're logged into the former, but not the latter (you can check this by trying this in another browser).

I don't know what kind of authentication scheme you have set up for your server, but you'll need to log into that on iOS before you'll be able to make that request.